# Is the backslash \ counted as a character in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

if i have a table which has columns with fixed lenght, Will mySQL count the backslashes as characters?

Example :

```
people(name[10],age[3])
```

If i store in the name column a MySQL escaped value like : `Blahblah\'s`
Will MySQL cut it at the quote?

Thanks

Comment: No, the backslash is not counted and therefore `Blahblah\'s` won't get truncated.  BTW why can't you try such things on your own?

Comment: @mjv because there is so many mysql versions...

Comment: @Axel - that's not a good reason.

Comment: @Stephen - If you're going to say "that's not a good reason", explain why. Pretty much everyone here is here to learn, and your comment is not very helpful.

Comment: @Aistina - if you insist.  The meaning of "\'" in SQL is not MySQL specific.  @Axel is assuming (with no evidence) that since some aspects of MySQL's SQL are version specific that all aspects are.  That is plain illogical.  Alternatively, (and IMO more likely) he is just using that as an excuse.

Comment: @Aistina - "Pretty much everyone here is here to learn".  On the contrary, a lot of people here are here to avoid reading a text book or doing a tutorial.  And some people are just here to get someone else to do their homework ... or even paid word ... done for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, escape characters do not add the length of `char` or `varchar` string, because escape characters are not stored at all.

```
CREATE TABLE a (name char(5));

INSERT INTO a VALUES ('1234567890');
INSERT INTO a VALUES ('12\'345678');

SELECT * FROM a;
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| 12345 | 
| 12'34 | 
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: More info: it's not that MySQL doesn't "count" the backslash as a character.  It doesn't store it at all.  The backslash is just how you communicate with the database in SQL.

Comment: @dkamins: excellent point; greatly improves the answer! Daniel must have been just like me, a bit peeved at Axel not trying things for himself, that he too only thought of answering by way of empiric evidence.  Indeed, it's not a matter of "counting", but a matter of difference between the representation of the string in scripts and display versus the effective format of the storage.  In scripts etc. we need the escape lest we ambiguously interpret the quote (is it part of the string or is it the quote used to end the string?). but for storage no such ambiguity is possible.

Comment: @mvj: Good point. Rephrased my answer to make it more accurate.