# Decoding mysql_real_escape_string() for outputting HTML

Tags: php, sql-injection, html-encode, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm trying to protect myself from sql injection and am using:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($string);
```

When posting HTML it looks something like this:

```
<span class="\&quot;className\&quot;">
<p class="\&quot;pClass\&quot;" id="\&quot;pId\&quot;"></p>
</span>
```

I'm not sure how many other variations real_escape_string adds so don't want to just replace a few and miss others... How do I "decode" this back into correctly formatted HTML, with something like:

```
html_entity_decode(stripslashes($string));
```

Comment: If the user can control $string,  then this is an XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 13):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't have to be decoded, it is only used for SQL, but escape characters are never stored in the database. And of course it shouldn't be used to sanitize HTML. There's no reason to use it before outputting web page data. Besides, `mysql_real_escape_string()` shouldn't be used on data that you're about to put into the database either. Your sanitization process should look something like this:

**Input**

1. Accept user input from a form or HTTP request
2. Create database query using prepared statements

**Output**

1. Fetch data out of the database
2. Run any user-defined data through `htmlspecialchars()` before printing

Using a database driver such as [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) will allow you to use prepared statements, which take care of escaping most inputs for you.

Comment: I would recommend prepared statements (e.g. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) over `mysql_real_escape_string`.  And `htmlspecialchars` is not always the right choice.  Sometimes white-listing is a better option.

Comment: Note! If you have 'magic_quotes' on, even with PDO you will need to use 'stripslashes()' before putting strings to database to avoid double slashes.

Comment: But no modern system should have magic_quotes on. That feature has been deprecated for years.

Answer (score 12):

You've got everything messed up.

## mysql_real_escape_string doesn't need any decoding!

If you get your data back with slashes, it means that it has been **escaped twice**. And instead of stripping out the extra slashes you just shouldn't to add them in the first place.

Not to mention that whatever escaping is obsoleted and you ought to

## use prepared statements

instead of whatever escape string.

So, never escape, never decode.
The problem solved.

Comment: $query="INSERT INTO table SET html='$html'"; is not standard SQL, you'd better use INSERT INTO table (html) VALUES('content'); This works in all databases, not just MySQL.

Comment: @Frank Heikens But I am working with mysql. And I use tons of mysql specific features. Go tell me not to use PHP as it not supported everywhere. What a nonsense comment!

Comment: As Guss pointed out, escaping is needed to protect your database against SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks you saved my life, I used prepared statement and mysql_real_escape_string which resulted in the double escaping :-)

Answer (score 8):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is used to prevent SQL injection when storing user provided data into the database, but a better method would be to use data binding using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) (for example). I  always recommend using that instead of messing with escaping.

That being said, regarding your question on how to display it afterwards - after the data is stored, when you retrieve it the data is complete and valid without any need to be "unescaped". Unless you added your own escaping sequences, so please don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

use the following function to remove slashes while showing on HTML page:

stripslashes();

eg.
$html=stripslashes($html);
OR
$html=stripslashes($row["fieldname"]);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on with the formatting as I can see it but your html form

```
<span class="\&quot;className\&quot;">
<p class="\&quot;pClass\&quot;" id="\&quot;pId\&quot;"></p>
</span>
```

should be simply;

```
<span class="className">
<p class="pClass" id="pId"></p>
</span>
```

When you get it back, before you put it into the database you escape it using mysql_real_escape_string() to make sure you do not suffer an sql injection attack.

Hence you are escaping the values ready for place the text is going next.

When you get it out of the database ( or display ANY of it to users as html) then you escape it again ready for that that place it is going next (html) with htmlentities() etc to protect your users from XSS attacks.

This forms the EO part of the mantra FIEO, Filter Input, Escape Output, which you should tatoo on the inside of your eyelids.

Comment: Are you sure he wants this form to be escaped? A i'm in deep doubts. If someone uses HTML formatting, they usually want it working, not as visible tags.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why this routine doesn't have a accompanying decoder routine. Its probably interpreted by MySQL the exact same way as if it were not escaped. You get the un-escaped results when you do a `$row=mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)';`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I took a stab at this the old fashion way and so far I am unable to see anything wrong with my approach. Obviously it's a bit crude but it gets the job done:

```
function mysql_unreal_escape_string($string) {
    $characters = array('x00', 'n', 'r', '\\', '\'', '"','x1a');
    $o_chars = array("\x00", "\n", "\r", "\\", "'", "\"", "\x1a");
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        if (substr($string, $i, 1) == '\\') {
            foreach ($characters as $index => $char) {
                if ($i <= strlen($string) - strlen($char) && substr($string, $i + 1, strlen($char)) == $char) {
                    $string = substr_replace($string, $o_chars[$index], $i, strlen($char) + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

This should cover most cases.

Answer (score -1):

Even if it's an old question...
I've had the same problem than Peter Craig. 
In fact I've to deal with an old CMS. In order to prevent SQL Injection, all $_POST and $_GET values are "sql-escaped". Unfortunatly this is done in a central point so all your modules are receiving all data sql-escaped! In some cases you want to directly display these data so you face a problem: how to display a sql-escaped string without gettng it from DB?
The answer is:
use stripcslashes (NOT stripslashes!!)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php

Answer (score -2):

I think a number of other answers missed the obvious issue...

You are using mysql_real_escape_string on the inputted content (as you should if not using prepared statements).

Your issue is with the output.

The current issue is that you are calling html_entity_decode. Just stripslashes is all you need to restore the original text. html_entity_decode is what is messing up your quotes, etc, as it is changing them. You actually want to output the html, not just plain text (which is when you would use html_entities, etc). You are decoding something you want encoded.

If you only want the text version to show up, you can use the entities. If you are worried about bad tags, use striptags and allow only the tags you want (such as b, i, etc).

Finally, remember to encode and decode in the proper order. if you ran mysql_real_escape_String(htmlentities($str)), then you need to run html_entity_decode(stripslashes($str)). The order of operations matters.

UPDATE: I did not realize that html_entity_decode also strips out slashes. It was not clearly documented on that page, and I just never caught it. I will still automatically run it though, as most html that I present I want left as entities, and even when I don't, I prefer to make that decision outside of my db class, on a case by case basis. That way, I know the slashes are gone.

It appears the original poster is running htmlentities (or his input program, like tinymce is doing it for him), and he wants to turn it back to content. So, html_entity_decode($Str) should be all that is required.

Comment: you are wrong. he need not to strip slashes. Ne need to add it properly. Do cure decease, not symptom.

Comment: He DOES need to strip the slashes out, as he ran escape string on it first. He encoded it, now he needs to decode it to get rid of the slashes in the output. Hence the \ appearing before the &quot;.

Comment: You have no clue how the thing works. So better ban yourself from answering until you learn some. No stripping needed. Try it yourself.

Comment: Finally, remember to encode and decode in the proper order. if you ran mysql_real_escape_String(htmlentities($str)), **no decodeing action required**. Go figure. if you don't want entities - just do not encode them. If you did - why to decode?

Comment: My database class runs real_escape_string before every insert. In order to get rid of the slashes in front of the quotes, I have to run stripslashes, or the slashes are escaped. 

I absolutely know how it works - I write this stuff all the time. He's trying to get his html back, there are slashes. How other than stripslashes do you plan on doing this without overcomplicating it? He needs to make sure he has the entities back first though!
The issues is he's running strip first, he should be running decode first.

Comment: `I have to run stripslashes, or the slashes are escaped. I absolutely know how it works ` ahahahahaha! what a funny comment :) Go turn magic quotes off, and read some manual entry on it. Your question was asked recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573150/is-the-backslash-counted-as-a-character-in-mysql

Comment: That question has no reference at all to this (it is not about whether slashes take up characters in mysql). A. I don't use magic quotes B. I stand corrected on needing to use stripslashes on html_entity_decode. It is not clearly documented on the manual page, and it is nice to know. HOWEVER, it is not necesarily a bad thing to get into the habit of doing (running stripslashes before anything else), in case you want the option of making the entities converted or not.