# Displaying symbols correctly after reading from database

Tags: php, mysql

I saved some text to SQL database after filtering it with the code below to prevent SQL injection.

```
$text = htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($_POST['inputedTextToSave'])); 
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$text);
```

Think that I am inserting the following string using the form;

```
The number 3 > 1
```

Now I want to read the data from the database. When I echo out the text from the database it displays it as follows.

```
The number 3 &gt; 1
```

How can I prevent this and make the text display correctly without symbols and all that.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decoding mysql\_real\_escape\_string() for outputting HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573332/decoding-mysql-real-escape-string-for-outputting-html)

Comment: Thanks that function did the job.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities`? That's going to double encode the entities, is that what you want? e.g. `µ` becomes `&mu;` then `&amp;mu;` (or I'd think, untested).